# How to reposition an animated smart object with some transform keyframes in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, animation

I created an animation on Photoshop video timeline.

The animation contains a smart object that its dimensions change at some transform key-frames.

My question is how can I reposition whole of this smart object and its animation?

Now the only way that i know is to select each key-frame and set the X and Y values for each one, but I'm looking for a way that do this at once since I need to make some duplicates of it and then arrange them and this way takes much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing to do is to export your only animation as a png sequence, then  import it back to the file as a video layer which you can move, resize and do whatever you want without hurting the animation inside. *In a way it's like an object in flash or a composition inside a composition in after effects.*